# Cocoa Bindings + NSArray + custom class

Tags: objective-c, nstableview, cocoa-bindings

I can't get my head around this: I have an instance of `NSMutableArray` filled with custom `Lesson`  objects. These objects have two `properties`: `name` and `selected`. I'm trying to use these `Lesson` objects in an `NSTableView`. One column should show the `name` as a string, the other `selected` as check box. I used the

```
- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex
```

method to return the name, which worked fine, however returning the value of `selected` doesn't work as expected - probably because the method gets called too often.

SO, can this be solved easily using the data source method or should I use Interface Builder and set up some bindings? The latter sounds better, however I don't know how I could bring my setup - `NSArray` with custom objects - into IB.

I would appreciate some ideas, Fabian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that bindins would work pretty good in your case.
You should use a NSArrayController binding to your array of Lesson's objects, lets call it "lessonsArray".
Select the NSArray controller and set its "Model Key Path" to "**lessonsArray**".
You must to create setter and getter to the "lessonsArray", otherwise it won't work.

Once you have put bindings to the NSArrayController, you have to bind the your NSTableView to it. In the reality, what you really need to bind now is the NSTableColumns, and I suppose you have two: name and selected. Bind them to the NSArrayController with this configuration:
Controller Key: **arrangedObjects**
Model Key Path: **name** or **selected**.

I hope that I've understood and helped you. Good luck